# What species is this aromatic plant found in a mountainous region of Greece?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This plant was found in the Taygetos mountains, Greece, and had a lemony smell.

Small plant about a foot high.

The shiny recurved leaves are reminiscent of rosemary, and the dry seed-heads seem rather distinctive.

Any ideas of Genus or species most welcome!

[image: dry seed-heads]
[image: plant habit]

Comment: The seed pods look like delphinium or a weird dwarf lilium species. Perhaps it is a mountain Lilly species. google lens said lilium and perhaps a weird heather variant. http://www.flora.dempstercountry.org/V.B.28.Ericaceae/Phyllo.empe/Phyllo.empe.pic1.jpg

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees - neither of the plants you mentioned are aromatic.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I had another look at this and now I'm pretty sure it's a Hypericum..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking another look at this, I think it's almost certainly a Hypericum species. Compare with Hypericum empetrifolium.

The fruit of Hypericum are very distinctive:
https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/104581263
[image: fruit of Hypericum empetrifolium]

The narrow revolute leaves of H. empetrifolium are also unlike other Hypericum species:
https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/69680320
[image: leaves of Hypericum empetrifolium]

Geographic distribution seems right:
https://powo.science.kew.org/taxon/urn:lsid:ipni.org:names:433403-1

[image: geographic distribution of Hypericum empetrifolium]

Answer (score 0):

A type of greek lavender with no blossoms anymore?
https://www.florealpes.com/photos/lavandulastoechias_5.jpg?PHPSESSID=0a72039f5036d91c7df80dd406b795b0

Comment: The desiccated seed heads seem like nothing that would come from a lavender flower though..